# android onKeyDown onKeyUp measuring time

Tags: java, android, android-keypad, android-keystore, java-time

I would like to mesure time between user presses volume up button and releases it (ex. if user keeps volume up button pressed 2 seconds the app will do something, and if 4 seconds the app will do something different).

At first glance it seems to be very easy thing. In order to control that I have the following part in my activity code:

```
    public final static long MINIMUM_VOLUME_UP_PRESSING_TO_ACTIVATE_DEACTIVATE=2000;

    public final static long MAXIMUMT_VOLUME_UP_PRESSING_TO_ACTIVATE_DEACTIVATE=5000;

    public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
               switch (keyCode) {
                  case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                  lastVolumeUpPressingDown=System.currentTimeMillis();
                  return true;  
               }
               return false;
            }

   public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
               long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
               switch (keyCode) {
                  case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                     if ((currentTime-lastVolumeUpPressingDown>=MINIMUM_VOLUME_UP_PRESSING_TO_ACTIVATE_DEACTIVATE) &&
                (currentTime-lastVolumeUpPressingDown<=MAXIMUMT_VOLUME_UP_PRESSING_TO_ACTIVATE_DEACTIVATE)) {
                                    , 
                    do something
                    return true;
                    }
                return false;
            }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't wok (doing something is not executed). When I analysed it a bit deeply (debug, adding toast displaying the difference between the currentTime and lastVolumeUpPressingTime) I discovered very surprising things. If I press and release volume button quite quickly, I get the difference between ex. 100 miliseconds. However when I press and keep it quite long ex. 2 seconds, I get the difference ex. 20 miliseconds.

Something is wrong, but why??????

Answer (score 1):

I had to put the code in my dispatchKeyEvent method rather than onKeyUp and onKeyDown for some reason but what's happening is the key down event is being triggered repeatedly as you hold the volume button down, so you have to just reset the time in the onKeyUp.  Hopefully you can get the idea from my code.

```
else if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP  && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        if(lastVolumeUpPressingDown == 0){
        lastVolumeUpPressingDown=System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Pressing down at " + lastVolumeUpPressingDown);
        }
        return true;
    }
    else if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Releasing at " + currentTime);
        long diff = currentTime - lastVolumeUpPressingDown;
        lastVolumeUpPressingDown = 0;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Button press lasted " + diff + " ms");
        if ((diff>=MINIMUM_VOLUME_UP_PRESSING_TO_ACTIVATE_DEACTIVATE) &&
                (diff<=MAXIMUMT_VOLUME_UP_PRESSING_TO_ACTIVATE_DEACTIVATE)) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Good enough, I would like to do something");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Notice how I'm only setting lastVolumeUpPressingDown if it's zero, and setting it to zero when the key up event occurs.